# SHBindToParent, get a parent pidl

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I'm implementing Windows-Explorer-view-like.

First i get desktop pidl via `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, &pidl)` and store it in class atribute. After my `IShellBrowser::BrowseObject` get called, i overwite the atribute with pidl is passed via this method. If i want to go up, i call call `SHBindToParent`, pass the stored pidl to it, but i got either `E_INVALIDARG` or desktop pidl. I suspect that i pass wrong PIDL in it.

How should i get parent PIDL right?

Comment: Please, paste your code snippet.

Comment: Um, `IShellBrowser::BrowseObject` takes a relative pidl, but `SHBindToParent` takes an absolute pidl.

Answer (score 1):

```
// C#
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("shell32.dll", EntryPoint="ILRemoveLastID")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern  bool ILRemoveLastID(System.IntPtr pidl) ;

}
```